# What is creating the gap between these two html elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, jekyll

Before the JavaScript for the tabs was added, the `li` were lining up nicely on top of the `div` underneath with no gap. As near as I can tell, the gap that now exists between them showed up when the JavaScript was added. Inspecting the first text item below the tabs on the [dev site](http://briligg.github.io/moonwards/index.html) (the `h1` in this case) shows a user agent stylesheet has been applied with `-webkit-margin-before: 0.83em`. Putting `margin: 0 !important;` on the `h1` does nothing.

Edit: I don't know if this will ever be of use to anyone, but the whole problem was because I'd changed the _config.yml file that jekyll uses, and didn't afterwards stop and restart the server, so it wasn't updating. In fact, another error was that I'd excluded the sass folder from the directories compiled to the _site folder, and that caused changes in the sass to not be reflected on the jekyll virtual server.

```js
function openContent (evt, contentType) {
  var i, tabcontent, tabheads;
  tabcontent =
document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent');
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  tabheads =
document.getElementsByClassName('tabheads');
  for (i = 0; i < tabheads.length; i++) {
      tabheads[i].className =
      tabheads[i].className.replace(' active', '')
  }
  document.getElementById(contentType).style.display =
'block';
  evt.currentTarget.className += ' active';
}
document.getElementById('defaultOpen').click();
```

```css
.outerDiv {
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 2rem; }

.innerDiv {
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.6);
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin: 15px; }
  .innerDiv p {
    padding: 0.5rem 1.2rem; }

ul.tabs {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1rem 0 0.3rem 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 2rem; }

.tabs li a {
  padding: 0.5rem 1.2rem 0.5rem 1.2rem;
  background-color: rgba(15, 10, 0, 0.4);
  color: #96912d;
  border-radius: 1.2rem 1.2rem 0 0;
  margin: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0.3rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px; }
  .tabs li a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: yellow; }
  .tabs li a:focus, .tabs li a .active {
    background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.6);
    color: #fac819; }

.under-tabs {
  margin-top: 0; }

.tabcontent {
  display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
 <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabheads"
         onclick="openContent(event,'intro')"
         id="defaultOpen">Intro</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabheads" onclick="openContent(event,'blog')">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabheads"
         onclick="openContent(event,'comments')">Comments</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="innerDiv under-tabs tabcontent"
     id="intro">
 
 <p>
 This project is building a series of virtual colonies on the Moon. 
 </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "_Putting margin: 0 !important; on the h1 does nothing."_ - It works for me on your dev site. The gap in your example is caused by the margin on the `<ul>` and the `<p>`

Comment: @Turnip maybe it isn't compiling from sass correctly... I've been trying to get that into it for a while now.

Comment: @Turnip gahd - it seems this all came down to a _config.yml file update that wasn't followed by a Jekyll server being restarted... Thanks for the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as commented, you are dealing with defaut margin, `<p>` in your snippet.

See  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing to understand how it can disturb your layout, what it is about and how to deal with it when it happens.

basic example here is to reset the margin-top of p to zero to erase the gap

```js
function openContent (evt, contentType) {
  var i, tabcontent, tabheads;
  tabcontent =
document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent');
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  tabheads =
document.getElementsByClassName('tabheads');
  for (i = 0; i < tabheads.length; i++) {
      tabheads[i].className =
      tabheads[i].className.replace(' active', '')
  }
  document.getElementById(contentType).style.display =
'block';
  evt.currentTarget.className += ' active';
}
document.getElementById('defaultOpen').click();
```

```css
.outerDiv {
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 2rem; }

.innerDiv {
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.6);
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin: 15px; }
  .innerDiv p {
    padding: 0.5rem 1.2rem; }

ul.tabs {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 2rem; }

.tabs li a {
  padding: 0.5rem 1.2rem 0.4em 1.2rem;
  background-color: rgba(15, 10, 0, 0.4);
  color: #96912d;
  border-radius: 1.2rem 1.2rem 0 0;
  margin: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0.3rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px; }
  .tabs li a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: yellow; }
  .tabs li a:focus, .tabs li a .active {
    background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.6);
    color: #fac819; }

.under-tabs {
  margin-top: 0; }

.tabcontent {
  display: none; }
p {margin-top:0;
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
 <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabheads"
         onclick="openContent(event,'intro')"
         id="defaultOpen">Intro</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabheads" onclick="openContent(event,'blog')">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabheads"
         onclick="openContent(event,'comments')">Comments</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="innerDiv under-tabs tabcontent"
     id="intro">
 
 <p>
 This project is building a series of virtual colonies on the Moon. 
 </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Though in the end this wasn't my problem, i'm accepting the answer because that is what i asked. I tried to set the margins to 0 a bunch of times and never realized i'd messed up with Jekyll and so the change weren't being incorporated.